# Deploying a RoR application in a separate folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

Let me start by saying I have never deployed a Rails app before.

I have a domain with a main site ran by PHP, let's call it `http://www.example.com/`.
I have began developing for Rails recently, and I'd like to host the new application I created on `http://www.example.com/myapp` while still keeping the original site intact.

The main site is hosted on Godaddy.com, but in my understanding they do not support rails well (my application is written in Rails 2.3.5). With that being said, I decided to host my rails app on Dreamhost.com.

So I have two questions: how do I deploy a rails app in a 'folder' on the main domain that actually links to dreamhost. Second, where do I get started with deploying the app?

Thank you!

Comment: If you are able, have a look at Heroku. The free Heroku account provides better performance than Dreamhost. I have been moving sites off Dreamhost because performance is quite abysmal for Rails apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would [setup a subdomain](http://css-tricks.com/put-a-subdomain-on-a-different-server/) on dreamhost: `http://myapp.example.com/`

Then if you want people to be able to access it via `http://www.example.com/myapp`, put an `.htaccess` redirect on your godaddy site:

```
redirect 301 /myapp/ http://myapp.example.com/
```

Information on deploying Ruby on Rails on dreamhost's wiki:
http://wiki.dreamhost.com/index.php/Ruby_on_Rails

Comment: not what I was looking for with the redirect, but kudos for the links. My less specific question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405845/redirect-folder-to-different-server
thanks!