# Redirect folder to different server

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, seo, hosting

I know you can redirect subdomains to a different server, but can you do the same with folders?

Say I have example.com. I can redirect mysubdomain.example.com to a different server, but can I redirect example.com/mysubdomain to a different server? I'd like to host a rails app in that folder on a site that runs php while still maintaining good search engines ratings (by not creating a sub domain which in my experience in recognized as a different site).

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: You might have better luck asking this at serverfault.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As brock Batsell suggested, a solution can be proxying the requests. you'll usually find this behavior in web apps that use long polling services, like chats, and need to proxy out those services to a second web server to reduce the load on the main one (usually, apache + lighhtpd)

Here is the basic usage (assuming youre using apache, and the other web-server is listening on the 81 port):

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
proxypass /folder-to-proxy http://localhost:81/folder
proxypassReverse /folder-to-proxy http://localhost:81/folder

<Proxy http://localhost:81/>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

Just replace the `localhost` and port number with your second server host and port.

Please note that even if you dont need to proxy the ftp traffic, in apache the `proxy_ftp_module` must be enabled as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can only do this via a proxy, which can forward all requests to the /mysubdomain folder to a particular IP and port, get the response, then return the response to the user transparently.

Pretty much any mainstream web server will have a module to do this if you have control over its configuration file.  (Apache has mod_proxy, nginx has HTTP Proxy, lighttpd has its own mod_proxy.)

Comment: +1 for mod_proxy, usually is used to switch some traffic to another webserver (e.g. lighttpd for long polling services aka chats)